# Blogger/Blogspot Aspect Ratio

Tags: image, blogger

I'm using the Contempo Theme on Blogger/Blogspot platform and I'd like to change the sizes of the thumbnail, but **it's important to keep the Aspect Ratio 1:1 (square)**.
For some reason that I don't know, if I change the size only some images are square but the others keep the original proportion (rectangular).

The original code is:

```
 <b:include data='{
    image: data:post.featuredImage,                                     
    imageSizes: [32, 64, 128, 256],                                     
    imageRatio: &quot;1:1&quot;,                                     
    sourceSizes: &quot;(max-width: 800px) 20vw, 128px&quot;                                  
}' name='responsiveImage'/>
```

What I've tried (among other things):

```
 <b:include data='{
    image: data:post.featuredImage,                                     
    imageSizes: [32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 945],                                     
    imageRatio: &quot;1:1&quot;,                                     
    sourceSizes: &quot;(max-width: 800px) 80vw, 512px&quot;                                  
}' name='responsiveImage'/>
```

I want to change the size at minimum of 512px (**the ideal would be around 945px x 945px**).
What's happening:
[image]

Comment: can you give example of what you are getting now or perhaps a url of image that didn't respect the 1:1 ratio

Comment: I only get the square aspect radio if the post width size is 400px; Now, I edited the post with a picture to clarify the result I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger does not make images bigger than the original size.

So for example if the original image size is `945x750` like the one in the picture, it will only respect the ratio if the `imageSizes` value is less or equal the smallest size (here 750)

`[256, 512, 945]` will result in
`256:256`, `512:512`, and `945:750` (instead of `945:945` because the image height is less than the provided size 945)

Comment: I think it's a bit difficult to understand it :/ , but... it's possible, in some way, to create a square in the sizes I need?

Comment: changing `p-k-no-nu` to `c` in the image url will do it, compare [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-In9nBjYRof8/YSqd6oy5JmI/AAAAAAAAKMY/TyH2ze4Vg2EoIwPbU4olGgOLU99zUoVqQCNcBGAsYHQ/w945-h945-p-k-no-nu/image.png) to [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-In9nBjYRof8/YSqd6oy5JmI/AAAAAAAAKMY/TyH2ze4Vg2EoIwPbU4olGgOLU99zUoVqQCNcBGAsYHQ/w945-h945-c/image.png); but there is no way to apply it in Blogger